# need static IP, have dynamic IP -- public NAT service?

Tags: tcp, nat

My ISP doesn't offer static IPs and I want to run a server. My dynamic IP changes once a week. I have a domain name with control over DNS records, but those don't change instantly. I am thinking that network address translation (NAT) would work: if I had a NAT server with a static IP address, I could make it map to my dynamic IP address and change the mapping instantly when needed.

Does anyone know of a public service that offers such servers? Or does anyone know of NAT server software that I could run on a machine that has a static IP?

Answer (score 0):

It used to be a free service but still you can find similar or you go on it

https://web.easydns.com/Dynamic_DNS.php

Easy Dns Provied solution to your problem  and there are many dns servers like **dynDns** that can provide a effective solution.

Comment: But if another dns server cached the old mapping, it might take minutes/hours a while to expire, rigth?

Comment: when you use online solution like easydns then it will not an issue  but on free ware there will be an issue of caching.

Comment: This: http://npcomplete.weebly.com/1/post/2013/07/how-to-set-up-a-web-server-on-a-dynamic-ip-address.html